# Gps with Lora (E32 433T30D)

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to receive data from GPS Neo 6m to Arduino and want to sent through LoRa (E32 433T30D).

GPS RECEIVE AND LORA SEND code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>


static const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 5;
static const int loraRXPin = 2, loraTXPin = 3;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;
static const uint32_t loraBaud = 9600;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);
SoftwareSerial lora(loraRXPin, loraTXPin);


void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);
  ss.println("KATHE");
  lora.begin(loraBaud);
  lora.println("ASHOK"); 
}

void loop() {
  // This sketch displays information every time a new sentence is correctly encoded.
  while (ss.available() > 0){
    gps.encode(ss.read());
    if (gps.location.isUpdated()){
      ss.listen();
      Serial.print("Latitude= "); 
      Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6); 
      Serial.print(" Longitude= "); 
      Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
      lora.listen();
      lora.print("Latitude= "); 
      lora.print(gps.location.lat(), 6); 
      lora.print(" Longitude= "); 
      lora.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
    }
  }

  }

LORA RECEIVE CODE is 

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2,3); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
} 

void loop() { // run over and over
  if (mySerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
    //Serial.println(" ");
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());

  }
}
```

Here I'm not getting gps data to the LoRa receiver. 
Please help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: set ss.listen() in setup(). you don't read `lora` so why listen? are the gps data printed to Serial Monitor?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  No I'm not getting gps data to the serial monitor or through lora. But individual codes if I run, getting data. Only whenever ever I'm clubbing the both codes I'm not getting the data

Comment: did you made the change I recommended? (the individual codes don't have two SoftwareSerial instances)

Comment: Yes I got it. At sending code no need create another serial port, we can directly use LoRa Rx and Tx to the arduino uno 0 and 1. If I use this method I'm getting data to the Receiver. Thank you so much for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lora we can connect directly to the arduino serial ports(0,1)- Lora Tx is connected to the arduino Rx and Lora Rx is connected to the arduino Tx. (this is for receiving data from arduino and must be connected these pins after uploading the code). 
(2,3) of other arduino to receive data to arduino from Lora. 
For sending there is no code like Bluetooth. And for receiving the following code helps you..

## include  SoftwareSerial mySerial(2,3); // RX, TX void setup() { // Open serial communications and wait for port to open: Serial.begin(9600); while (!Serial) { ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native j for the SoftwareSerial port mySerial.begin(9600); mySerial.println("Hello, world?"); } void loop() { // run over and over if (mySerial.available()) { Serial.write(mySerial.read()); //Serial.println(" "); } if (Serial.available()) { mySerial.write(Serial.read()); } }